# Unserscore template - how to pick a single value from the array?

Tags: jquery, templates, underscore.js

In my `json` I have 4 instance of the value example:

```
{
 details : [{"division" : "X"}, {"division" : "X"}, {"division" : "X"}, {"division" : "X"}]
}
```

in the above example, "division" has the same value, and it has 4 instance. How can i pick the one "division" value from this...?

my try:

```
<% _.each(details, function(item, index) { %>

            <span><%= item.divisionCode %></span> //I am getting 4 times.

        <% }) %>
```

so i tried like this:

```
<% _.each(details, function(item, index) { %>

                <span><%= item[0].divisionCode %></span> //But not works!

            <% }) %>
```

What would be the correct approach to do this?

what i expect is:

once I like to find the "divisionCode" if exist, let it print. later it need to skip. how to achieve this?

some thing like this?

```
<% _.each(results, function(item, index) { %>

            <span><%= !item.divisionCode ? item.divisionCode : null %></span>

        <% }) %>
```

I can do like this:

```
<span><%= details[0].divisionCode %></span>
```

But if first instance fail with divisionCode, then i could not able to print from others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% _.each(details, function(item, index) { %>
    <span><%= item[0].divisionCode %></span> //But not works!
<% }) %>
```

So, in this instance item refers to the array item and not the array itself, seeing as how you are using _.each to iterate over the array. So, item[0] is actually trying to access the property 0 on the item, which does not exist (it'll be undefined).

```
<span><%= details[0].division %></span>
```

This would work but I dont think that is what you're really after either.

I'm not exactly sure what you want but using underscore's (you might want to consider using lodash instead) _.[find](http://lodash.com/docs#find) method might be what you want. Find will return the first matching instance, you could use it like this:

```
<span><%= _.find( details, 'division' ) %></span>
```

> once I like to find the "divisionCode" if exist, let it print. later
>   it need to skip. how to achieve this?

In order to skip a value in an iteration just insert some logic to perform an if and check if the value exists first before outputting it.

Comment: Can't we  use the `_.find` using `underscore`?

Comment: Yes, underscore _.find will work fine. Lodash implements the same API as underscore, but often more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you want to fetch the single **division** value from the 
**JSON** collection object.But you are using  **divisionCode** insted of **division**
As the **JSON** object suggest it contains duplicate values. you can use the following code to remove duplicate items in **JSON** collections

```
var u = _.uniq(details);
```

The above code return collection of object.
Then use the following to print the object value in span inside your template

```
<% _.each(u, function(item, index) { %>
<span><%= item.division %></span> 
<% }) %>
```